# Divergent Moment Generating Function?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let's say I have a probability density function of $f_X(x)=\frac{x}{3}, \; \forall x\in(0,3)$ for some continuous random variable $X$.

Now I wish to find its moment generating function, I know that for something to satisfy the conditions of a mgf it must have some finite answer for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}f_X(x)dx$. My issue is that when I evaluate this integral, it diverges. Should my bounds for integration be my bounds for $x$, or have I made some error in understanding?

Comment: Are you sure those integrals diverge ? Looks to me there is no convergence problem at this stage (remember $f(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$ or $x>3$)

Comment: Ah! So really I should only be evaluating the integral on $(0,3)$ since my function is equal to zero everywhere else?

Comment: Exactly ! Integration by parts should do the trick.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much.

Comment: That does not look like a probability density: $\int_0^3 \frac x3\, dx = \frac32\not=1$.  Is it a cumulative distribution function?

Comment: Good spot! That's my bad, those 3's should be replaced by 2's.